# Akka and Play, integrating with non controller libraries

Tags: java, akka, playframework-2.3

I'm having a very hard time understanding Akka's integration with the Play framework. I'd like to integrate Akka actors into a non controller library class of my own creation, but the documentation only provides an example in a controller returning a Result (Play 2.3). I don't have any code written yet because I'm so vexed on how to move forward. Does anyone have any examples on the proper usage of Akka outside a controller? I found this example (Java 8):

```
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.mvc.*;

import static play.libs.F.Promise.promise;

public class Application extends Controller {
    public static Promise<Result> index() {
        return promise(() -> longComputation())
                  .map((Integer i) -> ok("Got " + i));
    }
}
```

but it looks like it has nothing to do with Akka at all. I'm so stumped I'm not even sure if I'm asking this question right, and I apologize for not having code samples.

My assumption is this: Place the above code sample in my library class and use it as specified, treating the "longRunningComputation()" as I would any other method call, and leave it at that. My concern at that point is that I'm not really leveraging what Akka has to offer.

Is there an Akka tutorial anyone would recommend to help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overall

Please keep in mind that Akka is (practically) in no way related or restricted to Play. There are thousands of systems built on top of Akka which have nothing to do with Play. Akka and Play just play well together.

---

## Akka + Play

It is perfectly fine to use Akka actors in the non-controller part of your application. You would just need a way to connect your controller to your actor system. This means you would need to find a way to talk to the actors in your actor system. There are (in general) two ways to do this in Akka. You either say (send) something to the actor or you ask him something.

### tell

Saying / sending (also known as **tell**ing or fire-and-forget) is done in Java with `actor.tell(message, getSelf())` and in Scala with `actor ! message`

```
import akka.actor.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.libs.Akka;
import play.libs.F.Promise;

import static akka.pattern.Patterns.ask;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        // select some actor from your system
        ActorSelection actor = Akka.system().actorSelection("user/my-actor");

        // now tell the actor something and do something else because we don't get a reply
        actor.tell("Something");
        return ok("Hello");
    }
}
```

Of course you are in no way limited to contact the actor only from your controller's methods.

The whole process messaging process can be of course very complex - it totally depends on your business logic. The actor *my-actor* from above will now receive the message and do lots of stuff at this point - forward it, spawn children, kill itself, do calculations, etc.

In Java you will have an actor like:

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;

public class MyUntypedActor extends UntypedActor {
  LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if (message instanceof String) {
      log.info("Received String message: {}", message);
      // do whatever you want with this String message
    } else
      unhandled(message);
  }
}
```

---

### ask

Asking is done with ... surprise .. the *ask pattern* - in Scala with `actor ? message`.

You already have found an example how to do it in Java. Please keep in mind that this time you get something back. This is the so-called `Future`. Once this future completes (successfully) you will have your result. Then you can `map` this result to some other result. See now why the `map()` call is there?

```
import akka.actor.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.libs.Akka;
import play.libs.F.Promise;

import static akka.pattern.Patterns.ask;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Promise<Result> index() {
        // select some actor from your system
        ActorSelection actor = Akka.system().actorSelection("user/my-actor");

        // now ask the actor something and do something with the reply
        return Promise.wrap(ask(actor, "how are you?", 1000))
                      .map(response -> ok(response.toString()));
    }
}
```

---

Some notes from personal experience:

- the Akka documentation is your friend
- take a look at the WebSocket connections use cases - build yourself a demo Play app where you support WebSocket and every connection is handled by an actor. Now think of a chat application - once I send something on the WebSocket, I would like that every other user of the app receives it - now this is fine case for "hello-world-Akka actors", isn't it

Comment: You are an absolute life saver. I checked out the Akka docs but couldn't find anything useful to the extent that you've presented it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad that I could help!